# Optimal data structure for time and source dependent log data for fast browsing?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've got field bus data that gets sent in packets and contains a datum (e.g. a float) from a source.

=> I get timestamps with a source ID and a value.

Now I want to create a little program (actually a logging deamon in C++ that offers a query interface over HTTP for displaying the data in a plot diagram) where the user can select a few of the sources and the interesting time range and then gets the data drawn.
This deamon will run under a Linux-based embedded system.

So my question is: what is the most efficient (query performance and memory consumption) data storage scheme for that data?

---

**Addendum #1:**

Although I think the algorithm question is very interesting stand alone I will provide a few informations about the problem that caused this question:

- Data rate is typically 3 packets / second (bursts up to 30/s are usual)
- Interesting data might be as old as a month (the more the better; the algorithm might use an hierarchy that allows ultra fast lookup for the last day, fast lookup for the last week and acceptable lookup for older data)
- the IDs are (at the moment) 32 bits wide.
- There are roghly 1000 IDs used - but it's not known in advance which and the user might use an additional ID any time
- The values stored will have different data types (boolean, integer, float - even 14 byte width strings are possible)

Doing a bit of math:

- Assuming a 32 bit timestamp + 32 bit ID + 32 bit values on average will create a datum to store of 12 bytes
- That'll be for a month 12*3*60*60*24*30 = about 100 MB of data to filter trough (in real-time with an 500 MHz Geode CPU)
- Showing the plot for the last day will filter out 1/30th of the data - that'll leave 3 MB to filter through.
- That 3 MB will be reduced to 1/1000th (= 3 KB) by showing only the relevant ID.

---

**Addendum #2:**

This problem asks basically how do I transfer a 2D dataset (time and ID are the dimensions) into memory (and from there serialize it to a file). And the constraint is that both dimensions will be filtered.

The suggested time sorted array is an obvious solution to handle the time-dimension. (To increase query performance an tree based index might be used. A binary search itself isn't so easy as each entry might have a different size - but the index tree covers that nicely and basically has the same underlying idea).

Going that route (first one dimension (time), then the other one) will result in a poor performance (I fear) for the ID filtering, as I have to use a brute force lookup.

Comment: Are you saying that your Linux daemon is running on a Geode CPU?

Comment: Yes. It's basically an Alix.1d that runs Debian and has a Geode CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the specific case but I can think that a possible solution would be to store events in pages and keep in memory just the page directory:

```
struct Page
{
    int id;
    int timestamp0, timestamp1;
    int bytes_used;
};
```

Every page only has events for a specific ID and all pages are of the same size (e.g. 4K).
When you receive an event you add it to the specific page if it fits, otherwise allocate a new page for that event ID.

When doing the searches you can quickly decide by looking at the index which pages from your data file are worth processing and you don't have to process the whole file.

Pseudocode for adding an event is:

1. find last page for ID x
2. if the event doesn't fit in the page allocate a new fresh page
3. store the event and update the index entry for the page

for doing a search you:

1. for each entry in the index
2. if the entry is about an ID you don't care about then go to next one
3. if `(page.timestamp0 >= tsmax || page.timestamp1 < tsmin)` then the page doesn't contain any interesting event, go to next one
4. this page contains at least a relevant event; load the page and process the events that are contained in the period `tsmin ... tsmax` you are interested in.

You can also avoid storing the index in the file (making the event logging operation faster) if you add an ID field once per page. Just when starting the server a full scan of all the data will be needed... may be or not this is an interesting option.

You can also easily decide how much data to keep... when no more free pages are available you can reuse (may be after storing away a zipped copy for archival) all pages that only contain events older than a certain date.

Comment: That's an very interesting thought!


Did I understand that correctly?


You are primarily sorting the data by ID, each ID forms a bucket / page and get's filled by timestamp/data pairs. If it's full, a new bucket / page for that ID will be generated - and so on.

Thus searching will be very fast for the IDs and then a binary search for the timestamp through the filtered dataset.

Comment: The idea is to keep an index in memory for all pages (using only the shown structure for each page). When you need to do a search you can just scan the index and decide which pages to load and search by filtering on ID and skipping pages that don't intersect your timestamp interval). In each page you only have events for a specific ID (so the ID doesn't need to be stored in the event... you need just timestamp, type and data) and it's not a problem to have events of variable size (you simply go to next page once a page is full and next event doesn't fit).

Answer (score 3):

You could just store your data in [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) and have your web-server run SQL queries against it. Using existing tools you can prototype rapidly and see how well it scales for your purposes.

Comment: That's a very good point and you are right! (But I'm sorry, as it's not an answer to the algorithm question, I can't accept it)

Comment: Algorithm is often the standard one: some form of an index for fast lookups by datetime. If you need fast lookups by other member/column just add another index. Databases make it easy, but may not scale well to more than 1000 queries per second. Do you need to query your data more than a 1000 times per second?

Comment: Write access will happen 3 - 30 per second. Read access will happen at most every second - but the "server" resources are limited and can't be extended, the data set to search is quite large for the little system and I need to optimize for little latency (i.e. the roundtrip Read request -> Answer). So I think the answer to use an SQLite for rapid prototyping (and go to the own solution only if it's not enough) is great - but I thought when I asked my question more at the theoretical aspects

Answer (score 1):

> most efficient (query performance and
>   memory consumption)

By this you probably mean something that is well balanced between the two. Also, I think that the data insertion must be fast.

The easiest and maybe sufficient solution would be to use plain array IMO as it is most memory efficient non-compressed form you can store the data. Thus each array element contains the `timestamp, id and value`.

When you query the data with two timestamps `begin` and `end`, you determine the locations of the timestamps in the array using `binary search`. Then, you traverse all the elements and fetch only the ones with id-s of data sources you are interested in. The array elements must be of course ordered by timestamps.

- The data takes O(n) memory, where the number of log entries is n.
- Data insertion is O(1)
- Data retrieval should be something like O(2*log(n) + n*m), where n is the number of elements. If you have more data sources you want to include in the query, then you can store the data source ID-s in a set, thus the complexity would be O(2*log(n) + n*log(m)).

There are of course other possibilities that can involve storing the transactions in trees, hashtables or something that mixes these with lists to get more detailed balance between performance/memory consumption.

Also, the problems arise, when the amount of logs is large. In that case, you should split the array into files and store the begin/end timestamps the files contain the logs. Then the implementation gets a little bit more complex.

Hopefully this helps somehow you to decide the best data structure / implementation for your solution.

Comment: Data retrieval O(2*log(n) + n*m)? I take it you're assuming a circular queue where you have to do two binary searches?

Comment: @Dave: because timestamps arrive in order

Comment: @Jim Mischel. Binary search takes O(log(n)) in an array. You need to find the indices for both begin and end timestamps, thus 2*log(n) and to be more precise 2*log2(n), but in terms of big-oh notation it does not matter that much. The n comes from going through the data. The n times m comes because you need to check if for every transaction if it has the ID of data source you are interested in. Having m data sources, you may need to do n*m comparisons. If m is larger, you can use some more efficient method for deciding whether the transaction is interesting or not.

Comment: Actually, if there are few data sources, you can give them ID-s that correspond to powers of two. When querying, you build an integer that has corresponding bits determining the IDs you are interesting set. Then, given the source Id of the transaction, you can use _binary or_ to decide if the transaction should be included in the output in constant time.

Comment: I've just updated the description to show the relation between time and IDs.
The IDs will be given by the user so there is no influcence (except putting a look up table inbetween that translates the user IDs to internal IDs that can be handled better)

Comment: @Timo: Why would you need to binary search to find the ending timestamp, when you're going to go sequentially through the list anyway, selecting just the sources you're interested in? That second search seems like a waste of time.  As for the rest, I understood ... just wondered about the constant "2".